# Github pages and custom domain from 123Reg

Tags: github, https, dns, github-pages

I've got a custom domain from 123Reg - www.mydomainname.co.uk - which I want to use for my github page - mygithub.github.io

I've managed to set it up so that www.mydomainname.co.uk works, but it isn't using https and therefore shows as unsecure, how can I make it use https?

Also, is there a way of allowing mydomainname.co.uk to work as well?

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure HTTPS is working on `https://www.mydomainname.co.uk` (by default it should). You can *[Enforce HTTPS](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/#enforcing-https-for-your-github-pages-site)* under your repository settings, so it would do the redirection from http to https.

To get your apex domain `mydomainname.co.uk` working, it's best if you do a redirection to `www.mydomainname.co.uk` from where you manage your DNS (some don't have the feature).